# How to show a notification a la Growl to all Linux consoles

Tags: linux, console, notifications

I'm building a textmode only linux netbook. I'd like to show information (like battery status) when pressing a hotkey, that would appear on top of whatever running program and disappear in a few seconds, on current virtual console. Is there some utility I could use ? "wall" is not what I mean (must not mess up the screen but be an overlay)

Comment: What about console window manager like dvtm - http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/dvtm/?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a utility that will do this. However, you could have a fair stab at implementing your own using the `/dev/vcs*` devices.

The [man page for `vcs`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/vcs) gives an example program that not only writes to a terminal screen via `/dev/vcsN` but also sets attributes via `/dev/vcsaN`.

A trivial demonstration can be seen with the following sample shell code. Note that if the screen scrolls or the top line is updated while the text is displayed, the *original* content will be replaced at the end of the message display time. (This isn't a true overlay; it's a temporary replacement.)

```
m="** THIS IS AN IMPORTANT MESSAGE **    "

for v in $(seq 7)
do
    d="/dev/vcs$v"
    if test -c "$d"
    then
        dd if="$d" bs=80 count=1 >"/tmp/save.$v"
        echo -n "$m" >"$d"
    fi
done

sleep 5

for v in $(seq 7)
do
    d="/dev/vcs$v"
    if test -c "$d" -a -f "/tmp/save.$v"
    then
        dd of="$d" bs=80 count=1 <"/tmp/save.$v"
        rm -f "/tmp/save.$v"
    fi
done
```